# Has anyone working Parallel 7 on Mavericks?

Tags: parallels-desktop, compatibility, macos

I am using Parallels 7. And I was not going to upgrade to Mavericks because I don't have any money now :(

But surprisingly, Mavericks is free!!! And this made me to think about upgrade... The only problem is Parallels 7 on my desktop. I already received a mail from Parallels company that PD7 won't work on Mavericks BETA. Anyway production release may different with beta, so I want to ask is there any people who can success to run PD7 on Mavericks.

And if it runs, but not perfectly, please let me know what part doesn't work.

I have to run Windows (7/8), OS X (Lion/Mountain Lion), FreeBSD server (9/10), CentOS server, Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1):

From meme1255's reply [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1636189)

> ```
> ExtensionsPath="/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/"
> cd "$ExtensionsPath"
>
> sudo kextutil prl_hypervisor.kext/
> sudo kextutil prl_vnic.kext/
> sudo kextutil prl_hid_hook.kext/
> sudo kextutil -d ./prl_hypervisor.kext prl_netbridge.kext/
> sudo kextutil prl_usb_connect.kext
>
> open /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app
> ```
>
> And you have to give parallels permissions to accessibility to get keyboard/mouse working:
>
> **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy Tab > Accessibility section**

You also need to reset Parallel's network setting.

Comment: It's best form to summarize the answer at a link so that people understand what the answer to the question here is - especially if a forum post or external link dies, changes or is unclear. +1 for being a new user and pointing the way to potential help.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. You did say that you need to "reset pd7's network setting," but giving some indication how would be very helpful.